# Вывод модального окна со ссылкой на сгенерированную страницу с текстом

Tags: php

Есть задача: после заполнения поля имени на сайте, нажимая на кнопку необходимо вывести модальное окно с текстом и ссылкой на страницу где будет генерироваться текст заполненный в поле.
Пока удается с помощью php просто при нажатии на кнопку перейти на страницу с текстом:

```
index.html
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">ВВЕДИТЕ ИМЯ ИМЕНИННИКА</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >ПОЗДРАВИТЬ!</button> 
</form>


form.php
Здравствуйте, 
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?> в html соответственно :
```

Comment: Иван, добрый день. Хочу сообщить, что StackOverflow - это не то сообщество, где будут делать всю работу за Вас. Приведите Ваш код и конкретизируйте вопрос. Вы не можете вывести при помощи `javascript` модальное окно?

Comment: я не знаю js 
мой код на php выглядит вот так :
Здравствуйте, <?php
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
?>

в html соответственно : <form action="form.php" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">ВВЕДИТЕ ИМЯ ИМЕНИННИКА</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >ПОЗДРАВИТЬ!</button>
</form>

Comment: Вынесите Ваш код в сам вопрос. Из комментария он не читабелен. И сразу вопрос: что вы подразумеваете под модальным окном? Его на `php` не сделать, так как это серверный язык программирования.

Comment: понятно, сейчас при нажатии на кнопку браузер отправляет на другую страницу, я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку всплывало бы окно со ссылкой на отправляемую страницу

Comment: Иван, прежде всего нужно понять различие между серверными и клиентскими языками программирования. На `php` практически невозможно сделать модальное окно, для этого существует `javascript`. В интернете есть много туториалов, `javascript` модальные окна, там даже знание языка не обязательно. Например, можете посмотреть [вот этот](http://dontforget.pro/javascript/prostoe-modalnoe-okno-na-jquery-i-css-bez-plaginov/).

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Comment: @MichaelPak Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего нужно понять различие между серверными и клиентскими языками программирования. На `php` практически невозможно сделать модальное окно, для этого существует `javascript`. В интернете есть много туториалов, ищите `javascript модальные окна`, там даже знание языка не обязательно. Например, можете посмотреть [вот этот](http://dontforget.pro/javascript/prostoe-modalnoe-okno-na-jquery-i-css-bez-plaginov/).